# Package release schedule

Tags: ros, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any deterministic criteria which decides when new / patched ROS packages are being released?
It would be nice to know in advance when the package upgrade will become available, especially for those waiting for an important bugfix. By "criteria" I mean the size of the Jenkins build queue, the number of packages to be released, a specific time interval etc.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194819/package-release-schedule/) by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2014-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The path from a bug being fixed to it being released is a multi-step process. First, the package maintainer must update the package version and run `bloom` to create a new release. Then, the released package is built on the ROS build farm, and goes into the testing repository. When the testing repository is stable, the updated packages in the testing repository are synchronized to the public repository.

I suspect you're actually asking about the final sync step. There is no set schedule. @tfoote does these when all of the packages for a particular ROS distro are built and stable.

The build status for Hydro is available at: http://www.ros.org/debbuild/hydro.html . You can get the build status for other distros by replacing 'hydro' with 'indigo' or 'groovy'.

The package maintainers occasionally coordinate on the [ros-release mailing list](http://lists.ros.org/mailman/listinfo/ros-release) about package releases and syncs, and the synchronization announcements are made on the [ros-users mailing list](http://lists.ros.org/mailman/listinfo/ros-users).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-10-12**:
There's also a summary of the testing repo here: http://wiki.ros.org/ShadowRepository where things are staged.

**Comment by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) on 2014-10-13**:
Thanks, that helps.
I would still humbly add that it would be nice to have a set schedule. I am, of course, unaware of how much effort it would take.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-13**:
The ros-release mailing list is probably the right place to start a discussion about setting up a fixed release schedule.